# Laravel 5 Fpdi unicode character

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, fpdi

I need help for my laravel project. I am using Fpdi to import PDF but when I display it on localhost, I have only unicode characters like this :

> %PDF-1.4 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream 
>       x�E�K�0D�9�,a�:i�d��H�|�4�ⓠr|�!y�aƗ!C*�r�y���{�98
>       L>|a�)w endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> stream x�]R�n�0�

**Here is my code:**

```
use setasign\ Fpdi;

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi\ Fpdi();
// add a page
$pdf - > AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf - > setSourceFile(storage_path("justificatif.pdf"));
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf - > importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf - > useImportedPage($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf - > SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf - > SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf - > SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf - > Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf - > Output();
```

**My route:**

```
Route::get('/testpdf', function() {
    return view('layouts/essai'); 
});
```

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return it like this
The browser doesn't know the type of the response unless you send it so it doesn't know it should show a pdf

```
...
return response($pdf->Output('S'))->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

**Source docs** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: The Response content must be a string or object 
    implementing__toString(), "object" given.

Comment: no other way to fix this ? maybe my pdf document is not adapt

Comment: Hmmm weird, I have an working example the way I answered.. try this `return response($pdf->Output())->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);`

Comment: Update it to `return response($pdf->Output('S'))->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);` to get the PDF [as a string](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm).